# Partition With Ranking to Solve A Clustering Problem

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, clustering

I have r restaurants and f friend where no of  f >> no of  r. Basically this is a clustering problem. I want to find the nature of  clusters(i.e which restaurant consists how much no of friends)

---

I am relating this with Partition problem. If I successfully calculate all
p(f) and then rank  those partition , Can I  get an idea of  total number of clusters and it's nature from it?

**Example**
[image: Partitions of 4]

Here I have taken 4 friends. They can be distributed in 5 ways.So 5 clusters possible. Now rank of -3 does not significant at all. I need to concentrate more on positive ranking Clusters.

Is this correct way?

*Note:-* Picture is taken from "***What is the crank of a partition?
-Daniel Glasscock, July 2014***"

Comment: [OEIS A026820](https://oeis.org/A026820) gives the number of partitions of $n$ into no more than $k$ parts, and also gives a recursion $T(n,k) = T(n,k-1) + T(n-k,k)$.  For $n=4$ and $k=4$ this is indeed $5$.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Nope! I am asking about the analogy which I have thought for whether is it correct or not?

Comment: I didn't follow your segue from restaurants and friends to clusters and partitions.  Is every friend assigned to some restaurant?  Are some assigned to more than one restaurant?   How will the cluster be used?  Are the friends to be clustered to optimize any particular utility?

Comment: Goal is to locate top k restaurants which consist more no of friends. Yes every friend must assign to a restaurant.